# reCaptcha doesn't validate

Tags: php, recaptcha

My reCaptcha implementation doesn't work. I studied the documentation from Google but it won't work.

The plugin I implemented like this:

```
<form role="form" name="formular" method="post" onsubmit="return chkFormular()">
        <div class="form-group" id="name">
            <label class="control-label" for="name">Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" placeholder="Name">
        </div>
        <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_public_key"></div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Abschicken</button>
 </form>
```

The captcha works fine. But now I want to validate it like this:

```
require_once('../php/recaptchalib.php');
$privatekey = "my_private_key";
$publickey = "my_public_key";

# the response from reCAPTCHA
$resp = null;

# was there a reCAPTCHA response?
if( $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"] ) 
{
   $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (
            $privatekey, $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"], 
            $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"], $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);
      if( $resp->is_valid ) 
      {
        //send_mail
        mail();
      } 
      else {
         if( $resp->error == 'incorrect-captcha-sol') {
            // do something
         }
   }
}
```

But it won't call the `mail()` method.

Answer (score 0):

PHP's `mail` function has three required arguments. Chances are it's just failing because of that. You should also consider using the [newly released reCAPTCHA version](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/).

Comment: Hm i think you get me wrong. Without captcha my mail would work fine. I edit my code and delete the send mail code because it work fine.
And i used the newly reCaptcha version, but i can´t find something in the documentation.

Comment: Then you need to explain **what** is not working. Do you get an error? What does `var_dump($resp->is_valid)` show? You've shown no troubleshooting steps and I'm still not clear that it isn't a problem with the `mail` call, especially as you're not showing us your actual code.

Comment: I think i write it down, thats the captcha works but the validation won´t work.
I found a reason now. I answer the question later.

Comment: "Won't work" is very vague. Your question is like saying "my car won't work" and neglecting to mention if it ran out of gas or is on fire.

Comment: Sry, but yesterday i didn´t know, why or what wouldn´t work. But in my answer I fix it, with try and error.

Answer (score -1):

I can solve the problem by my self.

I insert the captcha like this in my form:

```
<div class="g-recaptcha " data-sitekey="6Ldj_v4SAAAAAF8dEtmmJ0kv8kkLLEJuQfcdCOMZ"></div>
```

And then i add this php-script:

```
if (isset($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]) && !(empty($_POST["g-recaptcha-response"]))) {
    //send mail here
}
```

The trick is, that "g-recaptcha-response" in post is empty, if captcha didn´t solved. Otherwise there comes a non-readable string.

Comment: You're missing the entire validation logic. You have to send the response to `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=your_secret&response=response_string&remoteip=user_ip_address`. Otherwise, I can just have my spambot submit anything as the response and it'll work.